# Html-Js Label text transfer between HTML files; Is my use of one Id tag for all labels the issue?

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple labels with a similar id="productName". I am able to do the basics of transferrring label text data from one HTML file *(html1)* to another *(html2)* using JavaScript. I thereafter have an issue whereby the only text I receive in html2 is from the first label of *(html1)* even if I click on a button from the third product *(Product C)*.

*How intend the code to work:*
html1 -> Clicking on the buttons send anchor tag text to html2.
html2 -> The text from html is loaded into a text box.

**html1 code**

```
<div class="shop-content">
  <a class="black" id="productName">Product A</a>
  <button type="button" onclick="sendData(); return true;"<spanclass="price">Inquire</span>
</div>

<div class="shop-content">
  <a class="black" id="productName">Product B</a>
  <button type="button" onclick="sendData(); return true;"<spanclass="price">Inquire</span>
</div>

<div class="shop-content">
  <a class="black" id="productName">Product C</a>
  <button type="button" onclick="sendData(); return true;"<spanclass="price">Inquire</span>
</div>
```

This is accompanied by the script below on the same page *(html1)*

```
<script> 
function sendData(){
    var b=document.getElementById("productName").text, url="html2.html?productName=" + encodeURIComponent(b);
    document.location.href=url;
} 
</script>
```

**html2 code**

```
<input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject*" id="productSubject" required />

<script> 
window.onload = function (){
    var url = document.location.href, 
    params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
    data = {}, tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
        tmp = params[i].split('=');
        data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1]; 
    }
    document.getElementById('productSubject').value = data.productName;
}
</script>
```

**Issue**
I only receive *Product A*.

**Expected**
I would like to receive the respective *Product A*, *Product B* or *Product C*

.........
Sincere apologies if this was too long.

Comment: *"Is my use of one Id tag for all labels the issue?"* - Yes.  Consider your line of code here: `var b=document.getElementById("productName").text` - How do you expect that line of code to know which element you intuitively meant for it to find?

Comment: ids must be unique to a document

Comment: [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) has a specific meaning in HTML, please don't confuse matters by using it to mean something else!

Comment: anchor tag, relax hehe.. @Quentin but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are important to note first before fully answering this question.

Firstly, as mentioned in a comment, the `id` attribute of an element is meant to be a unique identifier. So you should never have more than 1 element with the same id.

Secondly, it doesn't look like you really even need to use the `id` attribute at all for this as each button and 'product' pair is contained within their own parent element. This means you can just have each button refer to a sibling element within the same parent to get your product information.

Next, I did notice a weird `<span` inside of your `<button>` element. I removed that because I'm not sure exactly why it was there (*I assume either a typo or possibly there was meant to be some additional HTML that wasn't included*).

Lastly, it looks like you are using the `<a>` tag around each product name, but there is no `href` attribute so I'm not sure what the purpose of the `<a>` tag is. For this reason, I am not using an `<a>` tag in my answer, but if for some reason you absolutely need that tag you can always add it back.

```js
const _SendData = event => {
  let productName = event.target.closest(".shop-content").querySelector(".black").innerText,
  url = `html2.html?productName=${encodeURIComponent(productName)}`
  
  // The redirect line is commented out for StackOverflow
  // Uncomment to redirect to the next page
  console.log(url)
  //location.href = url
}

document.querySelectorAll(".shop-content button").forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", _SendData)
})
```

```html
<div class="shop-content">
  <span class="black">Product A</span>
  <button type="button" class="price">Inquire</span>
</div>

<div class="shop-content">
  <span class="black">Product B</span>
  <button type="button" class="price">Inquire</span>
</div>

<div class="shop-content">
  <span class="black">Product C</span>
  <button type="button" class="price">Inquire</span>
</div>
```

**A Few Notes**
I opted to set the `onclick` event using event listeners in JavaScript, rather than set it directly in the HTML. So that part will look different than your original example, but functionally it will be the same.

This code does not take you to the **html2.html** page, mainly because this code snippet is on StackOverflow and will not be able to take you to a page that doesn't exist on here. So I have commented that line out and simply logged the url value to the console. Simply uncomment that last line in the `_SendData` function to have to send you to your **html2.html** page.

Lastly, ***how does this code work?*** When the `_SendData` function is run, it first gets the element (button) that called the function using `event.target`. From there we can use the `.closest()` method to get the parent element (*which has a class of 'shop-content'*). This could also be done using `.parentElement`, but I tend to use `.closest()` as it's a little more flexible. And then lastly, we use `.querySelector()` to get the product element using it's class of 'black' and grab the `innerText` value.

Because this function bases the text its grabbing relative to the button (*and `<div>`*) where the user clicked, it will always grab the appropriate text.